# Moment Matrix Positive Semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Let $\phi(x)$ be a probability distribution on$[0,1]$, and consider the moment matrix $M$ where the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry is
$$
M_{ij} := \int_0^1 x^{i+j}\phi(x)dx,
$$
or in other words, the expectation $\mathbb E(x^{i+j})$. Is there an easy way to see that this matrix is positive semidefinite? The matrix is definitely symmetric, and
$$z^T Mz =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n M_{i1}z_i
&
\cdots
&
\sum_{i=1}^nM_{in}z_i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1\\\vdots\\z_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$=
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^nM_{i1}z_i
\right)
z_1
+
\cdots
+
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^nM_{in}z_i
\right)
z_n
$$
$$=
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E(x^{i+1})z_i
\right)
z_1
+
\cdots
+
\left(
\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E(x^{i+n})z_i
\right)
z_n$$
I got stuck here aiming to prove it via the definition. Or perhaps there is an eigenvalue approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $M = \int_0^1 \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \vdots \\ x^n\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} x & \cdots & x^n\end{bmatrix} \phi(x) dx$, and hence
$\langle v , Mv \rangle = \int_0^1 (\langle v , \begin{bmatrix} x \\ \vdots \\ x^n\end{bmatrix} \rangle )^2 \phi(x) dx \ge 0$.

Comment: You want to write powers, not subscripts.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thanks for catching that!